# template class operator overloading problem

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to port some Visual C++ (VS2005) code so that it will compile under both VS2005 and C++ Builder XE.  The code that follows compiles fine under VS2005 but under C++ Builder XE, I get the following error:

[BCC32 Error] time_stamp.h(49): E2327 Operators may not have default argument values

Here is the code in question: (time_stamp.h)

```
template<typename counter_type>
class time_stamp
{
typedef time_span<counter_type>                     time_span_type;
typedef typename counter_type::value_type   value_type;

public:

/* some code removed for sake of this post, next line is the one causing the error */

friend time_span<counter_type> operator-(const time_stamp<counter_type> &first, const time_stamp<counter_type> &second)
{
  return time_span<counter_type>(first.m_stamp - second.m_stamp);
}

private:

value_type m_stamp;

}
```

The time_span template is as follows (time_span.h):

```
template<typename counter_type>
class time_span
{
public:
// TYPES
  typedef counter_type          counter_type;
  typedef typename counter_type::value_type value_type;

/* rest removed for sake of this post */
}
```

The C++ Builder compiler appears to not like the line:
friend time_span operator-(const time_stamp &first, const time_stamp &second)

I'm new to templates and this syntax escapes me or at least the compiler error I can't make sense of.  It appears, to me, that there are no default argument values despite the compiler saying so.  I'm interpreting the error message as saying const time_stamp & is a default value when it looks to me like a passed reference of type time_stamp.

Thanks for reading & replying.  Help understanding as well as fixing is most appreciated.

--- EDIT:

If I re-structure the call above as follows:

```
friend time_span<counter_type> operator-( (const time_stamp<counter_type>& first, const time_stamp<counter_type>& second) );
```

and outside the class definition, I describe the function:

```
template<typename counter_type>
time_span<counter_type> operator-( (const time_stamp<counter_type>& first, const time_stamp<counter_type>& second) )
{
return time_span<counter_type>(first.m_stamp-second.m_stamp);
}
```

I then get this error:

[BCC32 Error] time_stamp.hpp(56): E2082 '-(int (*)(const time_stamp &,const time_stamp &))' must be a member function or have a parameter of class type

Comment: On the edit: There are too many `()` parentheses in both the `friend` declaration and the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Replacing my previous answer!]

This is probably related to http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.16 .

Since the function you want to define is in fact a template function (it depends on `counter_type`), you should declare it before the `friend` declaration, and then declare a function template instantiation to be the `friend`:

```
// time_stamp.h
#include "time_span.h"
template<typename counter_type> class time_stamp;
template<typename counter_type> time_span<counter_type> operator-(
    const time_stamp<counter_type>&, const time_stamp<counter_type>& );

template<typename counter_type>
class time_stamp
{
  //...
    friend time_span<counter_type> operator- <> (
        const time_stamp<counter_type>&, const time_stamp<counter_type>&);
};

template<typename counter_type>
inline time_span<counter_type> operator-(
    const time_stamp<counter_type>& first, const time_stamp<counter_type>& second)
{
    return time_span<counter_type>(first.m_stamp - second.m_stamp);
}
```

Comment: I've tried all those options except the last one I think.  If I understand correctly, by "injected class-name time_stamp identifier" you mean replacing time_stamp<counter_type>, with time_stamp<int> or time_stamp<double>?

Comment: No, I mean replacing `time_stamp<counter_type>` with just `time_stamp`.  Doubt it would make a difference, though.

Comment: See replacement answer please.

Answer (score 0):

try as:

```
template<class counter_type>
class .... {
    friend time_span<counter_type> operator-(const time_stamp<counter_type> &first, const time_stamp<counter_type> &second);
};


template<class counter_type>
time_span<counter_type> operator-(const time_stamp<counter_type> &first,
                                  const time_stamp<counter_type> &second)
{
  return time_span<counter_type>(first.m_stamp - second.m_stamp);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not resolve my issue; I got exact same error message on the friend line.