# E2321 Declaration does not specify a tag or an identifier

Tags: c++, function, inline, declaration

I'm porting code from VS2005 to C++ Builder XE so that it will compile with both compilers.  The following code compiles fine under VS2005 but under C++ Builder I get the subject error message with the inline function rawtime();

(E2321 Declaration does not specify a tag or an identifier).

Here is the code:

```
template<typename counter_type>
class synchronizer
{
private:
// PRIVATE TYPES

typedef timer<counter_type>                     timer_type;
typedef reference_point<counter_type>           reference_point_type;
typedef time_data<counter_type>                 time_data;
typedef typename timer_type::time_stamp_type    time_stamp_type;
typedef typename timer_type::time_span_type     time_span_type;
typedef typename filetime_counter::value_type   time_type;
typedef typename counter_type::value_type       counter_value_type;
typedef synchronizer<counter_type>              this_type;

/* some code removed for sake of this post */

public:

typedef counter_type  counter_type;
typedef typename counter_type::value_type raw_value_type;
TIMESTATS_STMT(typedef statistics<counter_type> statistics_type);

inline raw_value_type rawtime() const   /* Subject ERROR coming from this line */
{
  return m_timer.now().value();
}
```

I tried following the results from this post which solved that particular problem but not this one.
[template class operator overloading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730788/template-class-operator-overloading-problem)

Thoughts/Commnets?

--- EDIT:

Feedback suggesting the TIMESTATS_STMT is acutal cause of the error so here is how that is defined.  Note that TIME_ENABLE_STATISTICS is commented out in both VS2005 and C++ Builder XE.

```
// #define TIME_ENABLE_STATISTICS
//

//
// Make null definitions
//
#define TIMESTATS_VAR(var, type, initial)
#define TIMESTATS_STMT(stmt)

#ifdef TIME_ENABLE_STATISTICS

//
// Make real definitions
//
#undef  TIMESTATS_VAR
#define TIMESTATS_VAR(var, type, initial) type var = initial
#undef  TIMESTATS_STMT
#define TIMESTATS_STMT(stmt) stmt
```

--- EDIT

offending line does appear to be the TIMESTATS_STMT line.  I was able to correct by undefining NULL #define as follows.

```
#ifdef TIME_ENABLE_STATISTICS
  TIMESTATS_STMT(typedef statistics<counter_type> statistics_type);
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `TIMESTATS_STMT` expands to it's hard to say, but I bet the problem actually occurs on the line of the macro expansion and is being tagged to the following line, which appears fine to me.

Comment: Thanks Mark, see updated post for how TIMESTATS_STMT is defined.  I tried commenting out the TIMESTATS_STMT line and got a slew of errors else where (of course).

Answer (score 2):

Wrong: `TIMESTATS_STMT(typedef statistics<counter_type> statistics_type);`

Correct: `TIMESTATS_STMT(typedef statistics<counter_type> statistics_type)`

Remove the semicolon after the macro. The macro is a powerful language extension, but sometimes very-very dangerous and unpredictable.

I like to use C++ macros, but they are evil.

Comment: Correction: they're C macros.  You don't have to blame C++ for those. ;p